# Install PHP-Redis for XAMPP on Mac

Tags: php, macos, redis, xampp

XAMPP 7.3 is installed and functional and localhost is working as expected. Now I would like to install PHP-Redis to test Redis.

I've been following the instructions here: https://www.9lessons.info/2016/12/install-xampp-70-on-ubuntu-and-mac-osx.html

So, I have installed PHP-Redis:

```
$ brew install homebrew/php/php70
$ brew install homebrew/php/php70-redis
```

I have then edited `php.ini` in the XAMPP directory (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini), and added the following line:

```
extension="redis.so"
```

After restarting XAMPP, Redis is not recognized in `phpinfo()`, and trying to set a Redis class results in `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Redis' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/redis_cache_test.php`

I have also tried in php.ini:

```
extension=/‎⁨usr⁩/local⁩⁨/Cellar⁩/php70⁩/7.0.19_11⁩/lib⁩⁨/php⁩/⁨extensions⁩/⁨no-debug-non-zts-20151012⁩/redis.so
```

However, the Redis plugin does not appear to be loading, where am I going wrong on this installation?

Comment: Hang on. If you're using XAMPP, installing PHP via Homebrew won't have any effect. (You also shouldn't be using PHP 7.0, which is [end-of-life](https://php.net/eol.php), and it'd be `brew install php@7.0` these days... Old tutorial!)

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes true, XAMPP installed PHP 7.3 separately. Following that guide I assumed PHP-Redis needs to be installed in terminal alongside a php installation, which in the tutorial given is 7.0. I'm stuck regardless on this installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution for XAMPP on Mac:

1. Open Terminal
2. Change directory to XAMPP: `cd /Applications/XAMPP/bin`
3. Install Redis using PECL: `sudo ./pecl install redis`
4. Add extension to `php.ini`: `extension="redis.so"`
5. Restart PHP, the Redis plugin should be visible from `phpinfo()`